# Equivalent of MATLAB variable field names in Python

Tags: python

In MATLAB you can do behave such as:

```
fldname = 'cost'; 
box.(fldname)  = 5;
```

Then `box.cost` will have `5`

I would also want to read from `box` with something like the following:

```
val = box.(fldname) #where fldname is set somewhere else like above
```

Is there a similar ability in Python?

Comment: You can't set new attributes on every object, but where you can, `setattr` will achieve your goal.

Comment: For reading, `getattr` can be used.